# How to resolve unhashable type: 'list' error

Tags: python, list, hash, hashtable

In the fowling code user enters two  lists, the first input is an integer`(N)` that shows number of elements in first list`(l1)` and 3rd input`(M)` is an integer that shows number of elements in second list`(l2)`.

The input is like below:

```
4
apple32
banana2
tomato3
potato
3
carrot
apple32
banana2
```

Since `apple32`  and `banana2` are in both lists, therefore, the output should be `2` which means there are two elements that repeated in both lists. My code raised with error:  unhashable type: 'list'

```
N = int(input() )
l1 = [[x for x in input().split()] for _ in range(N)]
M = int(input() )
l2 = [[x for x in input().split()] for _ in range(M)]
print(len(set(l1).intersection(l2)))
```

Comment: `intersection` takes a `set` as an argument; you are giving it a `list`.

Comment: @ScottHunter nope, it takes any iterable.

Comment: Anyway, you are trying to hash lists, `l1` is a list with lists in it. You try to put that into a `set` but `list` objects inside the list are not hashable, as the error message is stating. Don't try to hash lists. That is the solution.

Comment: Why are you even doing it like this? `[[x for x in input().split()] for _ in range(N)]` Note, that is just a wordy way of writing `[input.split() for _ in range(N)]`. But Why are you *splitting*? You probably just want `[input() for _ in range(N)]` In any case, you really should be trying to debug these small programs on your own. StackOverflow isn't a debugging service. You are expected to have at least done some research, maybe a few debugging prints, etc etc. and then in the question, tell us *exactly* what it is you don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your comprehension nesting

```
l1 = [[x for x in input().split()] for _ in range(N)]
```

The result of this is a list of lists, each of which contains a string, such as

```
[['apple'], ['banana'], ['carrot']]
```

A list is not a hashable item; you cannot make a set from it.

De-nest your comprehension:

```
l1 = [x for x in input().split() for _ in range(N)]
```

... and then apply `juanpa`'s simplifications.  This will leave you with a list of strings.  You can apply `intersection` directly to those structures.